# Categorizing a range of numbers in excel

Tags: excel, ranking

I have a range of numbers which I have ranked so there are repeating values as well. I want to categorize them into four buckets based on the highest value / 4.

For example:

```
A   1
B   2
C   3............
XYZ 3329
YZB 3329
```

When I divide 3329/4 = 832.25. I need the output as:

```
Values between 1 and 832.25 as P1
Values between 832.25 and 1664.5 as P2
Values between 1664.5 and 2496.75 as P3 and anything beyond that as P4.
```

I need these output in the next column. Can someone help me with the formula?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Can you try this:

```
=IF(A1<MAX($A$1:$A$10)*0.25,"P1",IF(A1<MAX($A$1:$A$10)*0.5,"P2",IF(A1<MAX($A$1:$A$10)*0.55,"P3","""P4")))
```

- `$A$1:$A$10` is the range of numbers in your sheet

Comment: Got it :) Thanks :)